# How can I convert a pandas dataframe column with birth year to age? (e.g. '1991' -> 28)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dateframe, with one column called 'Age'.
There are several thousands of birth years there (1970, 1953, 2018 etc).

How can I convert that year into an approximate age?
For example if the year was "1991" I would want it to show "28" instead.

I have tried playing around a bit with datetime, but without success.

```
df_age.head()

1970
1953
1953
1977
2017
Name: Age, dtype: int64
```

Comment: subtract from current year. Something like `df['Age'] = pd.Timestamp('now').year - df['Age']`

Comment: I will post now

Answer (score 2):

You can easily subtract the birth year from current year to get age.

To get current year using pandas you can do

`pd.Timestamp('now').year`

Hence you can do,

```
df['Age'] = pd.Timestamp('now').year - df['Age']
```

to get the `Age`. Keep in mind that this will over-ride the column value. If you don't want that, assign the result to some other column.

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import date 

def calculateAge(birthDate): 
    today = date.today() 
    age = today.year - birthDate.year - 
         ((today.month, today.day) < 
         (birthDate.month, birthDate.day)) 

    return age 

print(calculateAge(date(1997, 2, 3)), "years")
```

OR

```
from datetime import date 

def calculateAge(birthDate): 
    days_in_year = 365.2425    
    age = int((date.today() - birthDate).days / days_in_year) 
    return age 

print(calculateAge(date(1997, 2, 3)), "years")
```

If you want help doing it with dataframe. Comment so, but this is are 2 ways we can do it.

This is the answer you are looking for.

```
from datetime import date 
import pandas as pd
import datetime
def calculateAge(birthDate):
    today = str(datetime.date.today());
    curr_year = int(today[:4]); 
    age = curr_year-birthDate 

    return age 



lst=['1997','1998']
df=pd.DataFrame(lst)
df[0]=df[0].astype(int)
df['age']=np.nan
df['age']=df[0].apply(calculateAge)
```

Output-

```
   0  age
0  1997   22
1  1998   21
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need datetime, you just need to subtract the birth year from the current year. 2019 - 1991 = 28 for example.

The proposed solution `df['Age'] = pd.Timestamp('now').year - df['Age']` is certainly one quick way to do it. There are other ways that would work too.